# scraper with Laravel and Goutte

Tags: php, laravel, web-crawler

Iam going to scraper 4 website using Laravel and Goutte .

number of url(s) are 900 and I don't have any idea, how to send  url(s)

(I wrote crawler code and don't have any question about this)

but I don't know How to send  url(s)? 
Must I use queue or cronJob or ... ?

Do you recognize any package or tool or idea ? I don't have any idea to send 900 urls, 5 times in a day

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations of software are off topic because they spawn opinionated answers and they rarely will help other people in the future. I find it hard to believe you managed to write a crawler but struggle on loading the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote crawl code for websites, you can separate the links and store in CSV format file. You should write another script that enable to read with an exact numbers of these urls in CSV file and send you back. It's very easy in Ruby with open.csv library.